# Texture Mapping issue in blender

Tags: materials, texturing

I am having a problem mapping a texture. 
I am new enough to texturing so excuse me if this is a simple question
I am trying to texture a modular wall part. I am not using uv mapping, I am mapping the textures using Generated Coordinates.The problem I am having is as follows:

- I can get the texture to look ok in the zx plane but not in the zy
  plane.  In the zy plane the texture is blurred and not sharp.

The original texture png is file attached for reference. screen shot of the mapped texture also showing the mapping settings is attached.

*Is there any way of improving this mapping so that both planes are equally sharp?*

The model is a plane (for a wall) with the wood face extruded in y+ve  direction, The strange thing is that if a insert a separate cube and scale it in edit mode along the z axis, the textures map fine. See attached image for details
What am I doing wrong?

I managed to figure out the logic of transforming the image, but thats not helping

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks 
chris

[image]
[image]

Comment: I would recommend using UV mapping, as you have more control (and can easily fix things like this).

Comment: Thanks for that answer. I tried UV mapping, but when I unwrapped the wall the plaster section and the wood section did not keep their proportions. The model sizes are specific with the wall being 128*256 and the textures for the wall being 512px. Is there a Way I can lock porportions on uv unwrapping? 
If I could then I could still use the tileable effect of the textures. I didnt want to have to squash the textures in gimp to get them to fit manually to the exported uv map.

Answer (score 2):

Well, unless you're sure you've done so, I'd check to make sure that the scale and rotation were applied to the object. In object mode, select the object, and press CTRL-Akey.

Answer (score 2):

One technique that may help with UV unwrapping:

- Select all the faces you want to unwrap
- Ctrl-E(menu) Mark Seam
- 'U'(menu) Unwrap

If you then look at the UV/Image editor with the faces still selected, you will notice that they are all laid out with the proportions of the original polygons, but without regard to topology.  This is bad for some situations, but it does prevent any of the distortions that are necessary in other situations.  You can then drag them around and scale them however you like.

There is also an icon at the bottom of the UV editor whose tooltip says "Keep UV and edit mode mesh selection in sync" which makes it easy to pick a face in 3D edit mode, then adjust its position or scale in the UV window.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using nodes in the cycles render:

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> *> Vector > Mapping*

Place the Mapping node between the Texture Coordinates node and the Image Texture node. This will allow you to scale and relocate the image in various ways. You may also try changing the input from the Texture Coordinate node from Normal, to Generated, to UV, etc., until you get the look you want.

Remember also that in cycles the "materials" view will look different than the "rendered" view.